# How to align image below text header in Marp or Marpit

Tags: html, css, markdown, marpit, marp

I'm using Marpit via VScode. Here is mi minimum working example:

```
---
marp: true
---

This should go in to the header and picture should be bellow it, but right now it is the middle of the picture

![bg contain](https://csgeekshub.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/C-Program-compilation-steps-and-process.jpg)
```

Problem with this code is that it produces slide where text and images are aligned in to the center as it is seen on following picture:

[image]

I would like to have text as an Header rather than crossing image.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Marpit you have an [image syntax](https://marpit.marp.app/image-syntax) that enables basic image modification. In many cases, it is suitable to scale an image rather than putting it to the background. For headlines you typically use leading hashtags. Consider the following

```
---
marp: true
theme: default
style: |
    img[alt~="center"] {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
---

## A Beautiful Headline

![w:500 center](https://csgeekshub.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/C-Program-compilation-steps-and-process.jpg)
```

where I added `center` to horizontally align the image, which yields this slide:

[image: horizontally aligned image]

It is a matter of taste, but I tend to prefer the following arrangement with `justify-content` to position headlines at the top

```
---
marp: true
theme: default
style: |
    section{
      justify-content: flex-start;
    }
---

## A Beautiful Headline

- some valid point
- another interesting fact
- even more convincing

![bg right:50% w:500](https://csgeekshub.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/C-Program-compilation-steps-and-process.jpg)
```

as it leaves space for informative text as seen below

[image: floating image]

Comment: Thank you very much. If I understand correct then you are using style directive https://marpit.marp.app/directives which will be used for every slide? And also if either width or height (not both) are used as image parameter then image is resized by maintaining it's ratio? Is it also possible to somehow set image width of image e.g. to 80% of slide width, so I do not need to set exact size of image? Thank you very much

Comment: One more question: according to your second example it seems that all slides are wrapped in section tag?

Comment: You can pass relative sizes such as ```![bg right:50% h:10% w:80%](https://your_img_link.jpg)```, which changes the ratio. If you would like to retain the ratio, specify either width or height only. 

You are right about the second example, where the section tag would apply to all slides. To limit the scope you can 
```<!-- centered headline only on this slide -->
<style scoped>
  section{justify-content: center;}
</style>
```
Hope that helps.